# How can I avoid using to many @SerializedName s?

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit, android

In my android application I have defined too many model classes and I used upper case property names like this:

```
public String FirstName;
public String LastName;
```

Using this naming policy, `retrofit` fails to match the json filed names to my java classes because the web api sends camel case names:

```
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
```

Therefore I have to use `@SerializedName` attribute for each field to tell retrofit what the `json` name is. This is so hard because there a large number of these properties:

```
@SerializedName("firstName")
public String FirstName;
@SerializedName("lastName")
public String LastName;
```

*Is there any configuration in `GsonConvertorFactory` to avoid this?*

Comment: Don't start variable names with uppercase in java. Classes are StudlyCase, variable names camelCase. Enums UPPERCASE. That's been convention like forever.

Comment: I think you are looking for a `FieldNamingPolicy` https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html

Answer (score 3):

You should respect the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your fields.

Comment: Correction, it's not the answer you like, but you should follow to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although I accept that I should correct my naming convention, the following piece of code is the way of adding a custom naming strategy to the `Gson`:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String translateName(Field f) {
            String fieldName = f.getName();
            return Character.toLowerCase(fieldName.charAt(0)) + fieldName.substring(1);
        }
    });
```